# limiting full text mysql searches to exact matches

Tags: mysql, sql, search, full-text-search

I am trying to match a table with keywords against a text. Problem is, that the query does not return exact matches, but only the most relevant ones:

```
    SELECT name, name_safe, MATCH name AGAINST ('".$ad['text']."') as importance
    FROM $T2
    WHERE MATCH name AGAINST ('".$ad['text']."') AND cat_type = 4
    ORDER BY importance DESC
    LIMIT 1
```

$T2 contains keywords like

```
hunde welpen
chihuahua
```

I only want the query to return a hit if it is an exact match. So a search for "welpen" should not return a result.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Have a look at [Boolean Full-Text Searches](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-boolean.html).

Comment: thank you for your hint. I tried boolean. Unfortunatelly I could not solve it with that info. Boolean will only count the matches. I am looking for exact matches only.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood. But if it should be an identity then you can use the simple `WHERE name = '".$ad['text']."'` instead.

Comment: this would not allow to performa a full text search on the provided text against several hundred keywords inside a table.